# How to limit download bandwidth per IP?

Tags: networking, tc, qos

We are running Ookla Speedtest server and want to limit download bandwidth per IP (350Mbit/s per IP). And I cannot find some examples how to do that. All the examples with `tc` are about how to limit bandwidth to some set of IP addresses. But in our case destination IP may be anywhere on the Internet.

In some other question I found an idea that I could define e.g. 256 queues and then filter IPs by the last byte. But wouldn't 256 `ip filter` rules affect performance? And since this is Speedtest server I would like the best latency and throughput (within limit) possible.

Comment: Isn't that kind of contradictory to running a speedtest?

Comment: How big is your netblock?

Comment: You can filter on a specific address with the `u32` filter for `tc` (see `man tc-u32`, there are some examples available).